# Já, agora e logo ficam para quando?

Tags: sinônimos, advérbios

Reparei que há pessoas que dizem coisas como «vou fazer isto já», mas as suas ações demonstram que isso significa que «já vai ficar para depois». Comecei a pensar em quando é que *agora* e *já* acontecem.

Já sei que os seguintes advérbios são sinónimos, quando usados para falar do futuro (quer dizer, de coisas que ainda não aconteceram). Mas, será que alguns seriam entendidos por acontecer mais cedo, ou mais tarde, dos outros? Pode imagina que se colocam na frase «vou fazer isto ____».

- *já*
- *já, já*
- *agora*
- *agora mesmo*
- *logo*

Comment: « - Já vou, mãe... - Não é já, João Carlos, é agora!»

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acho que estás a confundir usos diferentes de *já*. A posição de *já* é importante:

> (1) Já faço/vou fazer isso.
>   (2) Vou fazer isso já.

As frases (1) não significam que vais executar a ação imediatamente. Significa que neste momento estás ocupado, mas que «em breve» atendarás a essa tarefa. Na frase (2), *já* está numa posição mais saliente. Indica que executarás a ação num futuro muito próximo, por oposição a uma outra qualquer altura. Se repetirmos *já*, a ideia de brevidade é ainda mais reforçada.

A frase (2) seria mais idiomática com *agora* ou com *já* depois do auxiliar (ou, talvez não tanto, depois de *fazer*):

> (3) Vou fazer isso agora.
>   (4) Vou já fazer isso.

Apesar de ser mais idiomática, em termos de significado (4) está algures entre (1) e (2), por isso a melhor opção para transmitir o significado de (2) é (3). Considera o seguinte diálogo, onde a diferença quase se anula, devido à primeira oração:

> A: O jantar está pronto. Vem para a mesa.
>   B: Estou só a acabar um e-mail, vou já/já vou [ir para a mesa]!
>   A: Vem já!

Na última frase, *já* tem o sentido de (2), mas na anterior o de (1), a versão com *já* no final assinalando um (relativo) maior grau de comprometimento.

Se usássemos *agora mesmo* teríamos um significado semelhante a *já, já*.

*Logo* tem um significado bastante diferente neste contexto; na frase que deste não significa *imediatamente*; pelo contrário, significa *mais tarde*. Também temos duas possibilidades de colocação:

> (5) Logo faço isso.
>   (6) Faço isso logo.

A diferença é semelhante àquela entre (1) e (2). A frase (5) indica que estás ocupado ou não te queres chatear num futuro próximo, mas prometes que executarás a tarefa num futuro relativamente distante, mas não muito (dali a uma horas ou quando muito dias). (6) põe em destaque a altura em que vais executar a tarefa; executá-las-ás *mais tarde*, não *agora*.

Answer (score 7):

O significado de "já", "já-já", "agora", "agora mesmo" e "logo" pode ser um tanto subjetivo.  Mesmo porque o interlocutor pode não ter a intenção de realizar a ação com a mesma brevidade que promete.  Mas vejamos a forma como eu entendo o uso desses advérbios:

> - **"Já vou atendê-lo"**, para mim significa em, no máximo, uns poucos minutos.
> - **"vou atendê-lo já-já"**, tenta dar enfase à brevidade, mas pode demorar tanto quanto o simples "já"
> - **"vou atendê-lo agora"** e **"vou atendê-lo agora mesmo"**, para mim podem ter o mesmo significado que os dois anteriores embora, literalmente, sugiram que a ação será executada no momento em que se fala.
> - **"logo irei atendê-lo"** é o único que me transmite menos brevidade que os demais, mas repito que é uma impressão pessoal.  Jà a expressão "logo mais" significa bem mais tarde: "iremos ao cinema logo mais".

Comment: Em portugal, diz-se _mais logo_: _vamos ao cinema mais logo_.

Comment: @Artefacto Também já ouvi  "mais logo" aqui no Brasil.