# Meaning and use cases of "já já" in spoken Brazilian Portuguese

Tags: português-brasileiro

Could someone explain to me the meanings and use cases of "já já"?

Comment: Related: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/2899/112

Comment: Explain to me. Sounds like you speak a Latin-based language.

Comment: Can you give us some context please?

Comment: Pelas respostas, parece que todo mundo esquece um dos principais usos de "já", que é para denotar ação já concluída: *Já terminei de varrer a sala, agora vou lavar a louça*. *Já já* não pode ser usada assim, e se refere sempre a ação ainda por fazer: *Terminei de varrer a sala, já já vou lavar a louça*. É um coloquialismo que significa o mesmo que *já* nessa segunda acepção; a duplicação é em princípio enfática, como o diminutivo em *agorinha*, mas como toda ênfase, pode acabar significando o oposto. Dependendo do contexto, *já já* é "imediatamente", ou, ao contrário, "quando der"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on the context. For an example, if you are waiting for your dish and the waitress says "vem já já", it's like a friendly way of saying that it will be here soon, but that she doesn't know the exact time.  Another example: "Ele está chegando já já" means that he is arriving soon, at any moment. The word já used by itself can be used in a more formal way, like in an order: "vem cá já!", said to a kid, means that he should get going RIGHT NOW :)

Answer (score 5):

**Já** - dá a ideia de imediatamente, agora ou "neste instante".
Exemplo: Já vou!

**Já, já** - dá a ideia de "daqui a pouco" ou  "aguarde só um momento"...
Exemplo: Espera que já já eu vou.

---

**Já** - it gives the idea immediately , at the moment , right now.

**Já, já** - it gives the idea of ​​"a little later" or "wait just a moment".

Comment: I see a parallel between *logo* and *já*…both mean something like "soon", but unlike "soon" or *cedo*, *mais logo* and *já já* are *less* instead of *more* soon. (Pior ainda *jamais*…)